# how to calculate new 3D point location after shifting

Tags: geometry, 3d

There are three 3D points on a rigid body P1(x1,y1,z1), P2(x2,y2,z2) and P3(x3,y3,z3). After tilting the body new locations of P1 and P2 are known. 
How to calculate the new location P3.

Comment: Is it a 2D (planar) body, or a 3D one?  If it's 3D, then you can't find the destination of $P_3$.

Comment: All these three points are in a rigid body and body is rotated. Planar only

Comment: Then why do the points have $z$ coordinates ??

Comment: By “tilting” do you mean that the body is rotated about the origin?

Comment: Just oscillating up and down. Imagine its a cube. All 3 points are on top surface. it will not rotate, can move, oscillate and go up.

Comment: So it’s simply been translated to a new position? That’s not what you said in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q$ be the orthogonal projection of $P_3$ on the straight line $P_1 P_2$. Let $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $Q = (1-t)P_1 + t P_2$. Let $r$ be the distance $P_3 Q$, and let $P_1^\prime,P_2^\prime,P_3^\prime$ be the images of the 3 points by the transformation. Let $Q^\prime = (1-t)P_1^\prime + t P_2^\prime$, then $P_3^\prime$ can be any point on the circle $C(Q^\prime, r)$ in the plane orthogonal to the line $(P_1^\prime, P_2^\prime)$.